# Handlebars js helper for condition check

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js

HTMl part

```
<input type="radio" name="checkbox_1"  id="checkbox_1" value="john" emp-id="{{name}}">
```

Handlebars js part

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('checked', function(emp-id,value){
 return emp-id == value ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
});
```

I want to compare state_id and value.If its true then it should be checked.

How can I do it?

I need the solution to change my helper.

Comment: There is a solution here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495007/handlebars-js-building-a-template-template

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`<input type="radio" name="checkbox_1"  id="checkbox_1" value="john" emp-id="{{name}}" {{checked this}}>`

with your helper modified to:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('checked', function(obj){
 return obj["emp-id"] == obj["value"] ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/wowuzoke/2/edit)

Comment: am getting this error, Error: Missing helper: 'checked'

Comment: @user3340300 It's working for me. Are you sure the `registerHelper` code is placed before the `Handlebars.compile` bit

Comment: Can you show the working demo.Your cide writes checked=checked in all the input types. Also it shows the last checked button. I want the checkbox to be checked only when emp-id and value is equal..But now the code gives result to non-equal values also..

Comment: you have compared two key values in json format. I want to compare emp-id and value in html input type. Also, you are using one input type with each function. However, i have multiple static input and amy passing json only for the emp-id.

Comment: @user3340300 I'm not sure I understand, could you give me an example?